# Querying a dataframe with SQL - Pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I am importing a dataframe from pandasql package then querying it using sql, it shows the following error when running the pandasql cmd. On the other hand, `print(meat)` shows that the data was imported properly

```
from pandasql import load_meat
meat = load_meat()           
print(meat)
print (pdsql.sqldf("select * from meat;", locals()))
```

> InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

FYI: pdsql is an alias that I created to use pandasql

Comment: Strange, your code is working for me. Can you show the full error message ?

Comment: It is strange, I uninstalled sqldf, reinstalled it
it worked, don't know what is the explication behind what happened!
Thx!

Comment: Maybe different versions? Anyway, good to know it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled sqldf, reinstalled it, it worked. Don't know why it didn't work at the first place.